# Placing GoogleMap Markers from PHP/SQL via XML

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to load a couple of LatLongs from an SQL DB into a Google Maps API on a [webpage](http://tconx.net/wellmap/map_test.html).  I've been following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3), even to the point of copying code straight from it since I'm such a Javascript noob.

What I have so far is:

-Coordinates can be added from the form on the right side of the page (they show up in phpMyAdmin)

-The php script to make an xml of the LatLongs works flawlessly (what do you mean I only get 2 links?)

The problem USED TO BE that the markers wouldn't show up on the map, but the map still loaded.  After I tried rewriting the page to better match the code in the tutorial, the map itself won't load.  I've read through some other threads on SE related to problems with this tutorial, but nothing in those seems to work...

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBvwCMuLz31gLXoawbDBntieQjGPMrf5vA" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      well: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.000, -115.000),
        zoom: 6
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("create_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="float:left; width:50%;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include _your_ code in the question itself, not a link to a page that will no longer exhibit the problem once you get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is your map doesn't have a size.  You changed this:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

to:

```
<div id="map" style="float:left; width:50%; height:100%"></div>
```

For that to work you also need to add additional css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Proof of concept snippet:

```js
var customIcons = {
  well: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.000, -115.000),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
load();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div id="map" style="float:left; width:50%; height:100%;"></div>

  <div style="float:right; width:50%;">
    <h1>WellMap</h1>
    <br>
    <!-- <img src="well_icon.png"> -->
    <br>

    <form name="new_well" method="" action="">
      Well Name:
      <input type="text" name="wellName" id="wellName"/>
      <br/>Well Latitude:
      <input type="text" name="wellLat" id="wellLat" />
      <br/>Well Longitude:
      <input type="text" name="wellLong" id="wellLong" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Well" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh God that is so embarrassing.  Well at least it works.  Thanks!